# Hurwitz zeta function

Tags: special-functions, riemann-zeta

I am using the below function to compute the Hurwitz zeta function from Riemann zeta function.
But I am not getting the correct results when compared with the value of Wolfram alpha Hurwitz zeta function. I am suspecting some issues with floating point errors but not sure. Can someone help me out with the explanation?

function h=hzeta(s,q)

z = zeta(s)

h = z - sum((1:(q-1)).^(-s));

where $q=1-500$ and $s=1-7.$

Thanks,

Comment: Your results are wrong because you misinterpret the Hurwitz zeta function. 
 It's definition is as follows:
$$\zeta(s,\nu)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{(n+\nu)^s}$$
From here, one can derive the following:
$$\zeta(s,\nu)=\zeta(s)+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{(n+\nu)^s}-\frac1{n^s}$$
which converges for $\Re(s)>0$ and $-\nu\notin\mathbb N$.

Answer (score 3):

I don't recognize the equation you are using for the Hurwitz-zeta function. The summation form is

$$\zeta (\nu,u)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+u)^{-\nu} \ \ \ \  \nu>1$$

and the integral form is

$$\zeta (\nu,u)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(\nu)}\int_0^\infty \frac{t^{\nu-1}e^{-ut}}{1-e^{-t}} dt$$

In my own Matlab function I chose the integral form because the summation is notoriously slow to converge.

Reference: K. Oldham, J. Myland, & J. Spanier, *An Atlas of Functions*, $2^{nd}$ Edition, Ch. 64, Springer.

Answer (score 2):

It's rather hard to explain your results if you don't say what your results are. For example $\zeta(2) = 1.644934067$ while $\zeta(2,3) = .3949340668 = \zeta(2) - (1/1^2 + 1/2^2)$.    What do you get?